# RelayCommand Execute delegate doesn't work if local variables are used

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

I am attempting to create an MVVM Light `RelayCommand` in a method:

```
protected RelayCommand NavigateToViewCommand(string viewName) {
#if false
    return new RelayCommand(() => {
        Debug.WriteLine("It fired.");
        Navigation.Navigate(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewLocator>().GetViewForNavigation("StudentPage2"));
    });
#else
    return new RelayCommand(() => {
        Debug.WriteLine("It fired.");
        Navigation.Navigate(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewLocator>().GetViewForNavigation(viewName));
    });
#endif
}
```

If I use the `viewName` parameter to the method in the Execute delegate for the `RelayCommand`, it will not fire.  I am binding this command to a button.  When I click the button, not even the `Debug.WriteLine` command fires (and a breakpoint placed on it won't break).

However, if I replace the `viewName` parameter with a hard-coded string that is the same as the value in `viewName`, the `RelayCommand` works fine.

Note that this code, where the command isn't used in a button executes without a problem:

```
void Test() {
    Command1.Execute(null);
    Command2("David").Execute(null);
}
RelayCommand Command1 { get { return new RelayCommand(() => Debug.WriteLine("cmd1 executed.")); } }
RelayCommand Command2(string msg) { return new RelayCommand(() => Debug.WriteLine("cmd2 executed: " + msg)); }
```

But if I bind `Command2` to `Button.Command` in Xaml, it doesn't execute:

```
public ICommand TestCommand2 { get { return Command2("Cater"); } }

<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding TestCommand2}" Content="TEST" />
```

Any ideas what might be going on here?

**UPDATE**

Further experimentation shows that using a virtual property in the Execute delegate instead of a parameter does appear to work.  The command created by `NavigateToViewCommand` in this code works fine when bound to button.Command.  That doesn't resolve the issue, of course; this is just more information.

```
// In base class:
protected RelayCommand NavigateToViewCommand() {
    return new RelayCommand(() => Navigation.Navigate(ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IViewLocator>().GetViewForNavigation(NextPageViewName)));
}
protected virtual string NextPageViewName { get { return string.Empty; } }

// In subclass:
private ICommand m_nextPage;
public ICommand NextPageCommand { get { return m_nextPage ?? (m_nextPage = NavigateToViewCommand()); } }
protected override string NextPageViewName { get { return "StudentPage2"; } }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my environment: this is in a Windows 8.1 WinRT application.  I am running 64-bit Windows 8.1 (on a MacBook Pro running Boot Camp, if that matters). The behavior is the same whether I run the app locally or in the simulator.  I installed MVVM Light today using nuget in VS 2013, and the version of GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll appears to be 5.1.1.35049.

Answer (score 0):

I prefered to use *in-built* `ICommand` pattern instead of this parameter passing to `RelayCommand` *ctor*, which means:

```
protected RelayCommand NavigateToViewCommand() 
{
    return new RelayCommand((viewName) => {
        Debug.WriteLine("It fired.");
        Navigation.Navigate(ServiceLocator.Current
                  .GetInstance<IViewLocator>()
                  .GetViewForNavigation(viewName.ToString()));
    });
}
```

and call execute like this:

```
NavigateToViewCommand().Execute("David");
```

It's a more gentle way to pass arguments to your command.
ps.: I did not try this. I hope it has no typo and it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I see what you're saying, but your method works best when the command is executed from code.  In my case, my goal is to bind my ICommand to Button.Command, and fully encapsulate the logic of what's going to happen (navigation, in this case) without also having to bind Button.CommandParameter.